# If the Wronskian of two arbitrary functions is zero, are they linearly dependent only if they are not zero at some point?

Tags: linear-algebra, wronskian, linear-independence

Given that the functions are not the solutions of the same linear differential equation, I know that $W = 0$ doesn't mean they are linearly dependent, for example $x^3$ and $ |x|^3$ are linearly independent but their Wronskian is zero.

On the other hand I saw this proof:

$$ W(y_1, y_2) = y_1 y_2' - y_1'y_2 = 0$$

$$ \frac{y_1'}{y_1} = \frac{y_2'}{y_2} $$

$$\int\frac{y_1'}{y_1} = \int\frac{y_2'}{y_2} $$

$$ ln(y_1) = ln(y_2) + C $$

$$ y_1 = Ay_2 $$

Is this proof valid and $W=0$ means LD only if you can divide by the functions?

Comment: If the Wronskian exists and is nonzero for at least one point, then the functions are independent.  For "arbitrary functions" the converges fails.  It could be that $W(f_1,f_2)=0$ identically, but $f_1$ and $f_2$ are still independent.  However: for solutions of an order $2$ linear differential equation, the converse is correct.

Comment: The error in the proof is that $C$, and thus $A$ also, isn't necessarily a constant. It can change value at any point where $y_1 = y_2 = 0$ and $y_1'/y_1 = y_2'/y_2$ will still be satisfied.

Comment: @eyeballfrog But how can you put $y_1, y_2$ in the denominator if they are zero at some point?

Comment: @GEdgar Can you please be more specific about what's wrong in the proof? It doesn't require $y_1,y_2$ to be solutions of order2 linear differentioal equation.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Application_to_linear_differential_equations for more on this.

Comment: @GEdgar I know my proof holds only if I can divide by $y_1,y_2$,  is my quenstion wasn't phrased well enough? It's not my native language.

Comment: So to be clear, the statement you're looking to show is "If $y_1,y_2$ are differentiable functions that are nonzero on some interval and $W(y_1,y_2) = 0$ on that interval, then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent on that interval."?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes! and also that they don't have to be solutions to the same linear differential equation.

Answer (score -1):

> > For the question in the title, the general answer is $\color{black}{NO}$.
> > In the  field $\mathbb Z_2$, the polynomials $p_1(x)=x^4+x^2+1$ and $p_2(x)=1$  do not have any zero and the Wronskian determinant
> > $W(p_1(x),p_2(x))=\begin{vmatrix}x^4+x^2+1&1\\4x^3+2x&0 \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}x^4+x^2+1&1\\0&0 \end{vmatrix}=0$ 
> > even then the polynomials  $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear but I meant that the relation $ \frac{y_1'}{y_1} = \frac{y_2'}{y_2}$ is always true, i.e $W=0$ for every $x$. In your example the wronskian is zero only at $x=0$ right?

Comment: @EB..Either $W=0$ for all $x$ or it is never zero. In my example, $W=0$ for all $x$ as second row is a zero row.

Comment: How exactly $4x^3+2x$ became zero?

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_2=\{0,1\}$, the coefficients $4$ and $2$ leaves remainder $0$ when divided by $2$ so for instance, $x^3+3x^2+4x+2$ is eventually $x^3+x^2$ in $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: I don't know what $\mathbb{Z}_2$ mean so lets say $y_1,y_2$ are real, integrable, differentiable and not zero at some interval. Then I can say that $W=0$ implies LD?

Comment: My answer shows that in finite fields, the conclusion is not true even when the functions are non zero with $W=0$.